# Combine two filter rules for an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-5

I'm using React Redux and I have an array of objects which I'm displaying in a list. I'm having an option to filter the list via a dropdown, depending on a name, and by two toggle buttons, based on kind.

```
<Table
  data={
    array
      .filter((a) => a.kind === showByKind)
      .filter((a) => a.name === filterValue)
      .sort(someIrrelevantSortMethod)
  }
>
```

Question is how do I combine the two `.filter()` rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining two filters means you need **both** to apply. In other words, you need `(condition 1) AND (condition 2)`.

So basically:

```
<Table
  data={
    array
      .filter((a) => a.kind === showByKind && a.name === filterValue)
      .sort(someIrrelevantSortMethod)
  }
>
```